# Is it possible to view control layout in visual studio designer but disable modifying from the designer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-designer

Is it possible to view control layout in visual studio designer but disable modifying from the designer?

You may be wondering why I would possibly want this. My answer is simple and here it is.

[image]

If you look closely, the labels have no logical alignment. That is certainly not how I laid them out. Frankly, I am so sick of this. At this point, it would be quicker for me to do everything by hand and verify with the designer view.

This issue arises when I use VS through a remote desktop connection, which I do quite often. I am not sure of the exact cause but I am 100% sure that it is the designer that is causing it. Any information will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have removed the profanity.. given that not everyone is comfortable with it and this is an open forum.

Comment: `At this point, it would be quicker for me to do everything by hand and verify with the designer view.` - **YES**. Professional WPF development is done by creating XAML by hand as opposed to using the Visual Studio designer.

Comment: Sorry for the profanity, I was a bit upset. I am rather sick of the bugs in VS. I am not writing in XAML. I am not too familiar with it. I am writing in C#. Either way, the designer is still involved. I want to disable the designer from making changes to my code. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

When viewing the designer, you can select Format -> Lock Controls

This will set the "Locked" property to True for each control on the form.

[image: Lock Controls]